# Nested Loop Unexpected Behavior

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, nested

I'm trying to debug my program with a nested loop to print out all the values in a 2d array. I was getting some unexpected behavior from the loop so i commented out some things and added a simple printf.

```
`int u = 0;
 int y = 0;
 char m = 'm';
 for (u; u < 12; u++)
 {
    printf("\n");
    for (y; y < 5; y++)
    {
        //transition[u][x] = &m;
        printf("o"); //this nested loop isnt working???? 
        //printf("%c", *transition[u][y]);
    }
 }`
```

Clearly this should print 12 rows of 5 'o's. But instead it is only printing out one row of 5 'o's followed by 11 newlines.

Edit: Thanks a lot! Silly mistake, I failed to realize that y would not set itself back to 0 on the second run through the loop. I guess overlooked this because I'm too used to Java initializing and setting the increment variable within the loop statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` initial statement doesn't mean anything:

```
for (y; y < 12; y++)
```

The first statement is just `y`. Which has no side effects so you are not actually resetting `y` to `0` after first innermost loop. So from next iteration of outer loop, `y == 5` and the inner loop is not executed at all.

You should do

```
for (y = 0; y < 12; y++)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not resetting `y` on your inner loop; try `for (y = 0; y < 5; y++)`.

This will reset `y` at the beginning of each loop.

p.s. This is really more of a code review question

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your question i assume that you are trying to print 5 o's in a line with 12 o's.

try this

```
for(u=0;u<12;u++)
{
    for(y=0;y<5;y++)
   {
         printf("o");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```